# Hilchos Shel Billam

Tags: tefilla, riddle, parashat-balak

What Halacha do you learn out from Billam?

Answer (score 2):

When Billam was to curse the Jews he had a second to curse them. How was he able to curse them?  **Tosfos** provides two answers. One he would say let them be cursed, second answer would be, if you start at the time of anger even if you keep going afterwards it still counts since you started at the proper time.This Halacha applies to *Davening* too.That is, if it is minutes before the end of *Zman Teffilah*, and you wont be able to finish *Davening* before the *Zman* is over the **Magen Avraham** says you say a *Teffilah Ktzarah* a shortened version of *Davening*. There are those who poskin as brought by the **Aruch Hashulchan** and others that if you start within the *Zman* when you are allowed to *Daven* the *Teffilah* is still good even if goes past **Zman teffilah**.This is a Halacha from Billam.

Comment: And this one too


http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/1946/kaddish-without-minyan

Comment: This is misleading. It is true that the Aruch Hashulchan says this, as do other Achronim. However, it is not at all clear that this is the accepted halacha. The Mishnah Berurah (99:5, among other places), and many commonly accepted Poskim say, that one needs to finish Tefilah by the zeman.

Comment: I mentioned 99:5. Also: 58:5, 234:14. I am not getting involved in the whole MB vs. AH shailah; I am just pointing out that it's not so simple. Please quote your source for minhagim in Europe.

Comment: YS: my information is that in Lita, the Derech Hachayim was the basic sefer halacha.

Comment: NU, I guess BO HAslishi Vaychriah Beinheim. ANYONE ELSE?